# Is it possible to set the class functions in the two functions?

Tags: c++, function, class, static-members

I don't know how to call my class functions into `printData(Testscore&)` and `readData(TestScore)`.

Also, could someone tell me why my `Average()` isn't being called to the `main`? I just learned about using static member variables and static member functions and was wondering if I am using them incorrectly.

The `readData` function:

1. Does not use copy constructor.
2. Reads all instance variables like the student's names and all their
   grades.
3. Uses functions to store the variables, name, element of each grade of array  pointed to private `pquiz`, and static member
   `grades` of how many grades to read.

The `printData` function:

1. Writes the name and average grade of the quizzes.
2. Uses copy constructor.

This is my program so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TestScore {
private:
    static int grades;
    string name;
    double *pquiz;
    double average;
public:
    TestScore();
    ~TestScore();
    void setName(string);
    static void setGrades(int);
    void setPquiz(double *);
    void setAverage(double);
    string getName();
    static int getGrades();
    double getPquiz();
    void readData(TestScore &);
    void printData(TestScore);
    double Average(double *, int);
    static void Grade(int);
};

TestScore::TestScore() {
    name="";
    pquiz=new double[grades];
    average=0;
}

void TestScore::setName(string name1) {
    if(name1!="1") {
        name=name1;
    }
}

void TestScore::setPquiz(double *pquiz1) {
    if(pquiz>=0) {
        pquiz=pquiz1;
    }
}

void TestScore::setGrades(int grades1) {
    if(grades1>=0) {
        grades=grades1;
    }
}

void TestScore::setAverage(double average1) {
    if(average1>=0) {
        average=average1;
    }
}

string TestScore::getName() {
    return name;
}

int TestScore::getGrades() {
    return grades;
}

double TestScore::getPquiz() {
    return *pquiz;
}


double Average(double *pquiz, int grade) {
    int count;
    double total=0;
    double average=0;
    for(count=0; count<grade; count++) {
        total+=pquiz[count];
    }
    average=total/grade;
    return average;
}

void readData(TestScore&) {

}
void printData(TestScore) {

}

TestScore::~TestScore() {
    delete [] pquiz;
    pquiz=0;
}

int TestScore::grades=0;
void TestScore::Grade(int a) {
    grades+=a;
}



int main() {
    const int grades = 3;
    const int students = 4;
    TestScore exam;
    string student;
    int grade;
    double *pquiz;
    double average;
    for(int i=0; i<students; i++) {
        cout<<"Student "<<(i+1)<<": ";
        cin>>student;
        exam.setName(student);
        cout<<endl;

        for(int count=0; count<grades; count++) {
            cout<<"Quiz "<<(count+1)<<": ";
            cin>>pquiz[count];
            exam.setPquiz(pquiz);
            exam.getPquiz();

            while(pquiz[count]<0) {
                cout<<"Error, invalid test score, please try again."<<endl;
                cout<<"Quiz "<<(count+1)<<": ";
                cin>>pquiz[count];
            }
        }
        exam.setAverage(average);
        cout<<exam.getName()<<" average is "<<Average(pquiz, grade)<<endl<<endl;
    }
    readData(exam);
    printData(exam);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `grades` should not be static at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `static` anywhere, at least not for now. You have too many variables of the same name, scattered all over the place. Try to clean them up.

```
TestScore::TestScore()
{
    name = "";
    //pquiz = new double[grades];//#grades is undefined
    pquiz = NULL;
    average = 0;
}
```

`grades` is not defined yet, it could be zero, or it could be -817. You should just remove that line, or you can put something like `pquiz = new double[10]` that's if you are sure the number of quiz will not exceed 10.

```
TestScore::~TestScore()
{
    if (pquiz) delete[] pquiz;
    pquiz = NULL;
}
```

`delete` `pquiz` only if it is not `NULL`

```
int main() {
    const int grades = 3;
    const int students = 4;
    TestScore exam;
    string student;
    int grade;
    double *pquiz;
...
```

This is a different `pquiz`, it is a pointer which points to nothing, it doesn't really exist, you can't use it like that.

Comment: _`delete pquiz` only if it is not `NULL`_ `delete NULL;` is fine, it will become a nop.

Comment: Why can't I declare the pointer in the main? Still doesn't help my question